# How can I make a Flux emit an extra element if no element has been emitted for a given time?

Tags: project-reactor

I am implementing a Heartbeat for a WebFlux SSE endpoint. To avoid a timeout in the client, I want to make sure that an element is emitted at least every, say, 10 seconds.

I came up with the following solution that emits a heartbeat element every 10 seconds regardless of whether a real element has been emitted or not:

```java
originalFlux.mergeWith(Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(10), Duration.ofSeconds(10)).map(ignored -> "heartbeat")
```

This is probably good enough for my use case but still I wonder if it is possible to emit the heartbeat only if no real element has been emitted in the last 10 seconds. I played around with the `timeout` operator which implements exactly the timing behavior I am looking for, but that emits an error and cancels the `originalFlux` instead of just emitting an extra element.

The following code using `timeout` passes my test but looks too complicated and as far as I understand could lose elements from the `originalFlux` if they are emitted between cancelling and re-subscribing to it:

```java
ConnectableFlux<String> sharedOriginalFlux = originalFlux.publish();
CompletableFuture<Disposable> eventualSubscription = new CompletableFuture<>();
return addHeartbeat(sharedOriginalFlux)
    .doOnSubscribe(ignored -> eventualSubscription.complete(sharedOriginalFlux.connect()))
    .doFinally(ignored -> eventualSubscription.thenAccept(Disposable::dispose))

private Flux<String> addHeartbeat(Flux<String> sharedOriginalFlux) {
    return sharedOriginalFlux.timeout(
        Duration.ofSeconds(10),
        Flux.mergeSequential(
            Mono.just("heartbeat"),
            Flux.defer(() -> addHeartbeat(sharedOriginalFlux))));
}
```

Is there a simple and safe way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessarily *simpler*, but another option could be to create a separate processor that can wrap the original `Flux` to provide a heartbeat (which shouldn't miss any elements):

```
public class HeartbeatProcessor<T> {

    private final FluxProcessor<T, T> processor;
    private final FluxSink<T> sink;
    private final T heartbeatValue;
    private final Duration heartbeatPeriod;
    private Disposable d;

    public HeartbeatProcessor(Flux<T> orig, T heartbeatValue, Duration heartbeatPeriod) {
        this.heartbeatValue = heartbeatValue;
        this.heartbeatPeriod = heartbeatPeriod;
        this.processor = DirectProcessor.<T>create().serialize();
        this.sink = processor.sink();
        this.d = Mono.just(heartbeatValue).delayElement(heartbeatPeriod).subscribe(this::emit);
        orig.subscribe(this::emit);
    }

    private void emit(T val) {
        sink.next(val);
        d.dispose();
        this.d = Mono.just(heartbeatValue).delayElement(heartbeatPeriod).subscribe(this::emit);
    }

    public Flux<T> getFlux() {
        return processor;
    }
}
```

You could then call it as follows:

```
new HeartbeatProcessor<>(elements, "heartbeat", Duration.ofSeconds(10))
        .getFlux()
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I tried it out and it passes my test, but I had to add a line to cancel the `orig` subscription when the downstream Flux is cancelled.
Just for curiosity: how would this behave if there were multiple subscribers and would it handle backpressure?

Comment: @lbilger Not tried either, but I believe it should handle multiple subscribers ok, but won't handle backpressure. If you have a look at some of the subclasses of `FluxProcessor`, one of those may be more suitable for your needs (different implementations often have different tradeoffs wrt. backpressure support, number of subscribers, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

[`Flux.switchMap`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#switchMap-java.util.function.Function-) is a good candidate for this job: It switches to a new `Publisher` (and cancels the previous one) whenever the original Flux emits an item. In your case, the new Publisher is your heartbeat `Flux.interval`, prepended with the original item `T`:

```java
public static Flux<String> addHeartbeat(Flux<String> originalFlux) {
    return originalFlux
            .startWith("heartbeat")
            .materialize()
            .switchMap(signal -> switch (signal.getType()) {
                case ON_NEXT -> Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                        .map(ignored -> "heartbeat")
                        .startWith(signal.get());
                case ON_COMPLETE -> Mono.empty();
                case ON_ERROR -> Mono.error(signal.getThrowable());
                default -> Mono.error(new IllegalStateException());
            });
}
```

Flux.switchMap is almost fit for the job, but it differs on two points from your desired solution:

1. It will only emit elements once the first element is received.

This means you have no heartbeat before the first item. This is solved by adding `Flux.startWith("heartbeat")`, which will emit `"heartbeat"` immediately on subscription, which then is processed by the `switchMap` into a heartbeat every 10 seconds.

2. The Publisher of the last element is never cancelled.

Since every generated Publisher is a `Flux.interval` that never completes, the `onComplete` signal will never reach the user. This is solved by transforming the `onComplete` signal into an emitted `Signal` item using  [`Flux.materialize()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#materialize--), then map the `onComplete` Signal into an empty Publisher just to cancel the previous Publisher. This also creates `onNext` and `onError` Signals, which we have to handle each:

a. `Signal.ON_NEXT` can be processed as usual, retrieving the original with `Signal.get()`
b. `Signal.ON_COMPLETE` is mapped to an empty `Mono` that immediately completes.
c. `Signal.ON_ERROR` should relay the error downstream using `Mono.error(Throwable)`.
d. The `Signal` enum contains more values, but they are not produced by `Flux.materialize()`.

Here is the test to test this solution:

```java
@Test
public void shouldAddHeartbeat() {
    Flux<String> originalFlux = Flux.just(25, 15, 7, 5)
            .concatMap(delay -> Mono.delay(Duration.ofSeconds(delay)).thenReturn(delay + " seconds delay"));

    Flux<String> withHeartbeat = addHeartbeat(originalFlux);

    StepVerifier.withVirtualTime(() -> withHeartbeat)
            .expectNext("heartbeat")
            .thenAwait(Duration.ofSeconds(10)).expectNext("heartbeat")
            .thenAwait(Duration.ofSeconds(10)).expectNext("heartbeat")
            .thenAwait(Duration.ofSeconds(5)).expectNext("25 seconds delay")
            .thenAwait(Duration.ofSeconds(10)).expectNext("heartbeat")
            .thenAwait(Duration.ofSeconds(5)).expectNext("15 seconds delay")
            .thenAwait(Duration.ofSeconds(7)).expectNext("7 seconds delay")
            .thenAwait(Duration.ofSeconds(5)).expectNext("5 seconds delay")
            .verifyComplete();
}
```